# I want to create a board in C# using the Miro (https://miro.com) API

Tags: c#, post

I am building a .NET Core 6.0 WPF application in Visual Studio 2022 Community.
I want to create a board in C# using the Miro (https://miro.com) API.
I have obtained CliendID and ClientSecret for authentication.
I added RestSharp with NuGet and wrote the code below.
It goes through to authentication.

After that, I am posting to api.miro.com/v1/board, but I get the error Unauthorized.
How can I post?

```
        public string MiroUserProfileUrl = "https://miro.com/app/settings/user-profile/apps";
        public string ClientID = "myclientid";
        public string ClientSecret = "myclientsecret";

        internal async void CreateBoardAtMiro()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://miro.com/app-install/?response_type=code&client_id="+ ClientID);
                var request = new RestRequest();
                request.Method = Method.Post;
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ClientSecret);
                var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                var result = response.Result;   //StatusCode: OK, Content-Type: text/html, Content-Length: )

                var boardMakeClient = new RestClient("https://api.miro.com/v1/boards");
                var boardMakerequest = new RestRequest();
                boardMakerequest.Method = Method.Post;
                boardMakerequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                boardMakerequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                boardMakerequest.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"name\":\"Untitled\",\"sharingPolicy\":{\"access\":\"private\",\"teamAccess\":\"private\"}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                var boardMakeResponse = boardMakeClient.ExecuteAsync(boardMakerequest);
                var boardMakeResult = boardMakeResponse.Result;   //StatusCode: Unauthorized, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 135)
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                var error = exception.Message;
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add the `boards:write` scope to the app?

Comment: Also, you haven't added the auth header to the `boardMakerequest`

Comment: Thanks David! I already add the boards:write.

Comment: How can I add auth header to the boardMakerequest?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Bearer token in the request to make a board. I suggest that you add the token

```
boardMakerequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ClientSecret);
```

Comment: Thanks Tobias! 
I added Bearer token in the request.
But same error StatusCode: Unauthorized, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 135

Comment: Thanks Lee. But this answer does not resolve the issue. so I can't mark this as answered.

Comment: I would guess you'll need to generate the a new token with the correct authorization scopes.

Comment: How can I generate the a new token with the correct authorization scopes?

Comment: I generete the a new token.
How can I use this token in code?

Comment: Pass the token in authorization header instead of client secret.

Comment: //boardMakerequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ClientSecret);
boardMakerequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
But same error.
StatusCode: Unauthorized, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 135)